# Как можно узнать какую версию php использует composer

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel, composer

Мне нужно узнать версию php и путь к файлу php. Сервер ubuntu 16.04

Comment: phpinfo() вам в помощь, узнаете и версию и где лежит конфиг

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если нет работающего сайта:

в консоли:

```
php -v
```

Более подробную информацию можно получить если войти в интерактивный режим и прописать phpinfo:

```
php -a
phpinfo();
```

Если сайт есть и вам нужно найти php.ini , то пропишите в index.php:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```